# Reading/Writing M365 Admin contacts

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, exchangewebservices, microsoft365

An administrator for a Microsoft 365 domain can create external contacts that are visible to users within that domain.  Those contacts can be seen in the M365 Outlook client under "Directory->All Contacts" or "Directory->Default Global Address list".

I need to use EWS to read and create these contacts. As a first step I'm just trying to read them, using FindFolder, against MsgFolderRoot of a user. Unfortunately the only contact folders that show up are the ones defined for the user in question, not the external contacts created by the Admin.  There are several contact folder classes that seem promising, such as "OrganizationalContacts" and "ExternalContacts" but there are no entries in those folders.

I could also use Graph for this if the capability is there. Any help on this problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Directory contacts exist in the Directory eg Azure AD or the local AD onPrem neither EWS or Graph can create these type of contacts then only thing automatable that can do that is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/new-mailcontact?view=exchange-ps

For reading Directory contacts the Graph is a better option it has a supportable endpoint via https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/orgcontact?view=graph-rest-1.0. EWS can do this via FindPeople but it's not documented and requires that you know the addressbook guid which isn't available via EWS.